# Render Android studio 2.3.3: File does not exist or is not a file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, render

I'm having trouble when rendering a project in Android Studio. It says a file doesn't exist or is not a file, but it exists and it is a file.

I have tried everything, lowering the SDK level to the one the manifest says. I also changed the theme, but nothing happens and now I can't even open the emulator, it says that it has been trying for 300 seconds to open.

This is the render problem:

[image: This is the render problem]

Here is the file that "doesn't exist" according to the problem:

[image: Here is the file that "doesn't exist" according to the problem]

The version of the SDK in the manifest is 22 and that's the one I'm using:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

This is the code of the layout where I call this file:

```
android:id="@+id/lyHeader"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@xml/header_color"
android:paddingBottom="5dip"
android:paddingTop="5dip" >
```

And here is the content of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<solid android:color="#71A2C7" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Most likely, that file should not be in `res/xml/`. Please edit your question and post the contents of that file, along with the layout resource where you are trying to use it.

Comment: I added the contents of the file and the layour resource where I'm trying to use it

Comment: `res/xml/` is for custom XML, or framework XML that does not have its own dedicated resource type (e.g., preferences, shortcuts, `FileProvider` metadata). In your case, you are defining a drawable. Move that file to `res/drawable-nodpi/` and see if you have better luck.

Comment: now it appears this problem: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

Comment: There is no `<item>` in your question. My guess is that none of the `button_*` files in `res/xml/` in your project belong there. If they define drawables, move them to `res/drawable-nodpi/`.

Comment: Worked perfectly! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put the Drawable file (file contains `shape` tag) to `xml` folder, so Android Studio interpretate it incorrectly. Just move it to `drawable` folder

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have res/font/regular.xml with this structure:

```
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fontProviderAuthority="com.google.android.gms.fonts"
    app:fontProviderAuthority="com.google.android.gms.fonts"
    ...
```

Reading [Troublesome XML Font-Family file with malformed app namespace in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63096980/troublesome-xml-font-family-file-with-malformed-app-namespace-in-android-studio) I removed `app:...` attributes.