# Troublesome XML Font-Family file with malformed app namespace in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, fonts, namespaces, font-family, android-fonts

In my Android Studio project I have a font file called 'cutive.xml'

The file path is:  resources -> font -> cutive.xml

The file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" //Lint problem here

app:fontProviderAuthority="com.google.android.gms.fonts"
app:fontProviderPackage="com.google.android.gms"
app:fontProviderQuery="Cutive"
app:fontProviderCerts="@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">
```

As you can see, the app namespace is not formed correctly:
**xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"**

In the MainActivity, I create a static Typeface object that references the font:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    typeface0024 = getResources().getFont(R.font.cutive); //app will crash if app namespace is corrected
    else typeface0024 = Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF,Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
```

The app loads correctly and finds the font, even though Lint claims that there is an error.
When I switch the app namespace to the correct form as such:

**xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"**
The app crashes on the line:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    typeface0024 = getResources().getFont(R.font.cutive);
```

the error logs gives the following reason: A RuntimeException

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Font resource ID #0x7f090000

How can I fix the error given by Lint? Or, should I just suppress the error and even though the app namespace is not formed correctly the font and app will load correctly.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by using the 'android' namespace NOT the 'app' namespace.

According to the Android docs make sure you the have the following support library:

**compile "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"**

Now it works and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


android:fontProviderAuthority="com.google.android.gms.fonts"
android:fontProviderPackage="com.google.android.gms"
android:fontProviderQuery="Cutive"
android:fontProviderCerts="@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">


</font-family>
```